# How to configure solr with django-haystack

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I am running solr 9.3 from docker and trying to integrate with django-haystack.
I am unable to configure `solrconfig.xml` and `schema.xml` and not sure where to add these files.

I tried generating `schema.xml` using `python manage.py build_solr_schema` but again I don't know how/where to put these files. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate Solr with Django using Haystack, you need to ensure that the Solr instance you're running has the correct configuration in place. Since you're running Solr from Docker, the process can be a bit different compared to a standalone installation. Here's how you can set it up:

1. **Generate the Schema**:

   You've already generated the `schema.xml` using:

   ```bash
   python manage.py build_solr_schema
   ```
2. **Customize Solr Docker Image**:

   You will need to create a custom Docker image that uses the base Solr image and then adds your custom configurations.

   Here's an example `Dockerfile`:

   ```
   FROM solr:9.3

   # Copy custom schema.xml and solrconfig.xml to the appropriate core directory
   COPY schema.xml /opt/solr/server/solr/my_core/conf/
   COPY solrconfig.xml /opt/solr/server/solr/my_core/conf/
   ```

   Replace `my_core` with the name of your core or the core you plan to create.
3. **Build Your Custom Docker Image**:

   In the same directory as your `Dockerfile`, run:

   ```bash
   docker build -t custom_solr:9.3 .
   ```

   This will create an image named `custom_solr` with the tag `9.3`.
4. **Run Your Custom Docker Image**:

   You can now run your custom Solr image. If you haven't created the core yet, create it first:

   ```bash
   docker run --name solr_instance -d -p 8983:8983 custom_solr:9.3 solr-precreate my_core
   ```

   Again, replace `my_core` with the name of your core. If the core is already created, you can just run the container without the `solr-precreate` command.
5. **Connect Django Haystack to Solr**:

   In your Django `settings.py`, make sure you point Haystack to the correct Solr URL:

   ```py
   HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
           'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/my_core',
       },
   }
   ```

   Remember to replace `my_core` with the name of your Solr core.
6. **Final Checks**:

   With everything set up, restart your Django server and check if Haystack can communicate with Solr. You might want to run `python manage.py update_index` to ensure data is indexed properly.

Remember, when using Docker, the configurations inside the container are ephemeral. If you remove the container, you lose those configurations. By creating a custom Docker image as described above, you ensure that you can always start a Solr container with your specific configurations.

Comment: This worked well! Is there any official documentation link to this ? If yes, please add it. It will be really helpful!

Comment: Sorry, It's from our company's internal wiki, as CEO, I can share it. :)

Comment: I actually copied solrconfig.xml from somewhere and i'm facing some issue related to it. Is there a way to generate this xml ?

Comment: yes, `python manage.py build_solr_schema` will create new one for you.

Comment: that will create schema.xml. What about solrconfig.xml ?

Comment: The solrconfig.xml file is more about Solr's core operational configurations, like caching, request handlers, query settings, etc.

If you want use any `solrconfig.xml` the default onve will use auomatically, also if you have your own local solr, you can see your `solrconfig` here path_to_solr/server/solr/configsets/data_driven_schema_configs/conf/solrconfig.xml